# Use jQuery .append() recursively

Tags: jquery, append

I have below code

```
$('.plus_sign').click(function() {
        $(".country").append(`<div>
                <select name="" id="">
                    <option value="">sdfasfdasd</option>
                    <option value="">sdfasfdasd</option>
                    <option value="">sdfasfdasd</option>
                    <option value="">sdfasfdasd</option>
                </select>
                <input type="text">
                <i class="fa fa-plus plus_sign"></i>
            </div>`);
    });
```

When I am click on `plus_sign` I am appending the HTML. But only the first plus sign is working. Appended plus sign is not working.

Comment: You need to delegate the handler to whatever Dom contains the plus sign. The handlers are added to what's on the page, new items won't have it. This is a dope but I'm on mobile and searching too hard.

Comment: It working for me. https://jsfiddle.net/Lgfquw30/

Comment: Thanks @HpLam for your comment. You are failed to understand. My one also works in your way. But my issue is I am adding plus sign in each `.append()`. I would like to make it like first plus sign so that the newly added plus sign can append() also. Thanks.

Comment: @abuabu Sorry for not understanding you, can you use On. Try it https://jsfiddle.net/ompk3jwb/

Comment: Thanks @HpLam. Your solution is working. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initial event handler is only for the `.plus_sign` that already exist in the DOM. If you dynamically add them, you'll have to add a new event handlers to those as you add them. Or assuming `.country` is hard coded, you could use `.on` with a selector:

```
$('.country').on('click', '.plus_sign', function() {
  $(this).append(`<div>
    <select name="" id="">
      <option value="">sdfasfdasd</option>
      <option value="">sdfasfdasd</option>
      <option value="">sdfasfdasd</option>
      <option value="">sdfasfdasd</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text">
    <i class="fa fa-plus plus_sign"></i>
  </div>`);
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/on/